# Why can you remove a point from each space and demonstrate that one is connected while the other is not, thus showing nonexistence of a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

I have seen this used several times, but have not really understood why. Consider $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$. I can remove ${0}$ from the second space and still have a connected space, but removing any point from the first space leaves it disconnected. Why is this a valid proof?

Also, assuming subspace topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f:[0,1)\to(0,1)$ were a homeomorphism, and let $a=f(0)$. Then $f\upharpoonright(0,1)$, the restriction of $f$ to $(0,1)$, would be a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)\setminus\{a\}$. In particular, it would be a continuous map of the connected space $(0,1)$ onto the non-connected space $(0,1)\setminus\{a\}$, which is impossible: continuous maps preserve connectedness.

Comment: So, in particular the restriction of a homeomorphism is still a homeomorphism onto it's image? Could you outline why?

Comment: @Jack: simple: the map is still bijective, the restriction of a continuous map is continuous (and the same holds for the inverse!)